# Problem multiple instance proxy wcf service c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I'am working in a `wcf` service in `c#`. I need to create a intance of a diferent class in a `BL` and `DAL` structures, but in my form I have this:

```
public BaseServiceReference.BaseServiceClient proxy ;
public BaseServiceReference.BaseServiceClient proxyGroups;

public List<User> list;
public List<Group> listGroup;
public User SearchModel;
public List<EnumBase> estatusList;

public Users()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    proxy = new BaseServiceReference.BaseServiceClient();
    proxyGroups = new BaseServiceReference.BaseServiceClient();
    proxy.setWorkBL("User", typeof(int).ToString());
    proxyGroups.setWorkBL("Group", typeof(int).ToString());

    estatusList = Tools.GetEnumList<Estatus>(true,"All");

    listGroup = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Grupo>>( proxyGroups.GetStandarList());

    CB_Estatus.DataSource = estatusList;
    CB_Estatus.ValueMember = "Id";
    CB_Estatus.DisplayMember = "Name";

    var lisGr = (from g in listGroup where g.Status.Value.Equals((int)Status.Active) select new { g.Id, g.Name }).ToList();
    lisGr.Insert(0, new { Id = -1, Name = "All" });
    CB_Group.DataSource = lisGr;
    CB_Group.ValueMember = "Id";
    CB_Group.DisplayMember = "Name";

    dataGridView1.CellPainting += DataGridView1_CellPainting;
    LoadGrid();
}
```

In my method `setWorkBAL` I have this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public class BaseService : IBaseService
{
    [DataMember]
    public static dynamic BL { get; set; }

    public void setWorkBL(string name, string type)
    {
        Type tp = Type.GetType("BL." + name + "BL, BL");
        var instance =  Activator.CreateInstance(tp);            

        dynamic file = instance;
        BAL = file;
    }
}
```

But when enter in the line

```
proxyGroups.setWorkBL("Group", typeof(int).ToString());
```

take the string param  `Group` in the firts var proxy affter use to load a `gridview`.

What is the problem?

Comment: A bit of a guess but ... don't use `static` here: `public static dynamic BL { get; set; }`

Comment: I try this but show a error for null value